# A Puzzle That Doubles Back Obscurely

Tags: steganography

Can you find the name of a reptile concealed in the following text? (Astute guesswork tolerated.)

> Rise, eager eagles! Silence, piccalilli imp! Prosper, revamp. Imagine ennui. Karmic crosstalk.

Comment: Well I found the red herring. That's mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reason this one didn't work is twofold. I made a semantic leap that is apparently rather difficult to follow and I also underestimated the notoriety of a certain pet/invasive species.

First the leap. I thought that

> if I marked the highlighted text as a "red herring" then people would look
>  elsewhere for the answer. Well, people were fairly quick off the mark 
>  spotting that if you take the first letter of every odd word it spells
>  "kipper" backwards. The first letters of the even words spell "cerise"
>  backwards. Similarly with the last letters. I had a lot of fun picturing 
>  different ways of combining the words acrostically. A kipper is a herring, 
>  of course, and cerise is a shade of red. That, I thought, clearly marked 
>  that block of text as a "red herring".

So where is the answer?

> In the "following text" which I helpfully bracketed off for you.

So what is the answer?

> "astu*te gu*esswork tolerated". The [tegu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegu) is an invasive species in 
>  Florida. They are also intelligent and make great [pets](https://pethelpful.com/reptiles-amphibians/why-tegus-are-the-best-pet-lizards). I did some 
>  asking around and I had not realized that I happen to move in circles
>  where tegus are much better known than among the general population. 
>  I upvoted Tom's answer which was very much on the right track and,
>  as a bonus, contained a Michael Stipe reference. I really liked the
>  ouroboros guess. I had no idea that this one wouldn't get solved.

Oh, well.

Comment: Nice explanation. I'm qui*te gu*tted to be outfoxed by a cerise kipper even when spelled out forwards, backwards and by other posters!

Answer (score 12):

Well, I observe that

> the words divide into pairs, each of which match at start and end -- you could form them into loops.

I don't see any names concealed in obvious ways although

> the first letters read backwards form KIPPER and the last letters read backwards form CERISE, both words. (Though I didn't notice that this was literally a RED HERRING until I read Will's comment...)

Perhaps the answer -- concealed semantically rather than syntactically, as it were -- is

> ouroboros?

Comment: You have indeed found the red herring doubled backward. The reptile is non-mythical and is concealed in a standard manner. There is a semantic element to the puzzle, though.

Answer (score 3):

Second attempt at this slippery one:

> Maybe *Cerise Kipper* is a 'double' red herring that reveals the answer
>   
>  **Credit to Gareth McCaughan and Will

This could be obscuring

> Cerise → Red  and  Kipper is a necktie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kipper_tie
>
>  So the reptile could be a:
>
>  **red-necked keelback** : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhabdophis_subminiatus
>  
>  with keel back for the doubles back in the title and the snake obscured by a not so red herring

**Edit This is the first attempt:**
Just grasping that it is the horrible

> Asp

Perhaps because of

> *Astute guesswork tolerated* may be a clue and this phrase has letters of length 6, 9 and 9
>
>  Counting from the beginning of 
>
>
>   Rise, e*a*ger eagle*s*! Silence, *p*iccalilli imp! Prosper, revamp. Imagine ennui. Karmic crosstalk.
>
>
>  position 6 → a
>  position 6 + 9 = 15 → s
>  position 15 + 9 (I need to count "!" but not "," as a character) = 24 → p

Comment: Good thinking. Perhaps the answer is less complicated, more obscure.